# How to program a tool which combines different components? (RPi)

Tags: python, bash, installation, sh, raspberry-pi3

the question seems not to be concrete enough, so let me explain: I programmed an Webapplication to viszualize data of different sensors in a wireless network. The sensordata is stored in a SQLite-database, which is connected as client to a MQTT-Broker. The whole project is implemented on a RaspberryPi3, which is also the central node of the network.

For the whole project I used differnet softwares like apache2, mosquitto, sqlite3. Furthermore the RPi needs to be configurated, so external Hardwre can be connected to it (GPIO, I2C, UART and some modules).

I wrote an installationguide with more then 60 commands.

What is the most efficient way to write a tool, which installs an configurate the Raspberry with all needed components? (sh, bash, python ...)

Maybe you can recommend me some guides which explains sh and bash.

Comment: Why not just create an image that can be burned to a card?

Comment: I already created an image, but it would be nice to have a executeable program which installs all required softwares, librarys and interface configurations. Just in case on the same RPi running other programs, which not depends on mine and should not be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

I would configure one installation until you are satisfied and than use dd to clone your sd-card image. You can us dd again to perform the installation on another raspi.

Best regards, Georg